# How to copy values dynamically from one object to 'this' without modifying the destination in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

After searching everywhere, I didn't find a working answer.

How to map values dynamically from one object to 'this' **without modifying the target** in Typescript?

```
const bigTodo = {
  name: "aaaaaaa",
  unwantedProperty: "Nooooooo"
}

.....

export class SmallTodo {
    name: string;

    constructor(bigTodo: any){
        _.assign(this,bigTodo)       // NOT working
        _.assignIn(this,bigTodo)     // NOT working
        _.merge(this,bigTodo)        // NOT working
        _.extend(this,bigTodo)       // NOT working
        Object.assign(this, fields); // NOT working

        for (const prop in bigTodo.keys()) { 
          if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            this[prop] = bigTodo[prop]; // NOT working not compatible with type 'any'
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
SmallTodo = {
    name: "aaaaaaa"
}
```

UNWANTED result:

```
SmallTodo = {
    name: "aaaaaaa",
    unwantedProperty: "Nooooooo"
}
```

Comment: So basically you don't want unwatedProperty in SmallTodo. that's what your problem is. right?

Comment: Yes exactly. How to do it dynamically?

Comment: I think you might need to initialise properties in class with some values like name: string = "";

Answer (score 1):

When you initialise property with some value you can call getOwnProperty on this. Something like below

```
const bigTodo = {
  name: "aaaaaaa",
  unwantedProperty: "Nooooooo"
}

class SmallTodo {
  name: string = "";

  constructor(bigTodo: any) {    
    for (const prop in bigTodo) {
      if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        this[prop as keyof typeof this] = bigTodo[prop];
      }
    }
  }
}


console.log(new SmallTodo(bigTodo));
console.log(bigTodo);
```

Comment: It does work, but you need to initiate "name".  I'm looking for a short and efficient way to not use "this.name = bigTodo.name" at scale

Comment: In the solution we did not use "this.name = bigTodo.name"!

Comment: Yes but name needs to be initiated. Is there a way with Lodash?